# TreeView refreshed when click on ComboBox

Tags: c#, events, combobox, treeview

Cause I don't know what cause the problem exactly, allow me to introduce a little bit of the project I am working on first.

It's a Windows form based application. Two major controls are TreeView and TabPage. Each TabPage associated with a TreeNode, so when the TreeNode is clicked, the corresponding TabPage will show up. This is done by using event "AfterSelect", once I clicked on the TreeNode, it will trigger the event to display the corresponding TabPage. And there are other controls on each TabPage, like TextBox, ComboBox etc. One more thing I've done on the TreeView is, I made the SelectedNode to stay highlighted even after the SelectedNode lost focus. I uesed event "Enter" and "Leave", so when enter the corresponding TabPage, I will change the SelectedNode backcolor to "MenuHighlight", and change the backcolor to normal after left the TabPage. (I start to see the problem after I added this "highlighting" SelectedNode feature.)

OK, it's a slightly long introduction. Thank you for reading, I appreciate your time.

It's basically working as I wanted. But there is a glitch. Everytime I select a TabPage, if I click on the ComboBox on that TabPage, the TreeView will refresh. But only for the first click, afterwords the TreeView won't refresh. And it only happened on the CombBox, I can't repeat this problem on TextBox, CheckBox or RadioButton.

Did anyone see this problem before? Any clue what could cause the problem? Again, thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you debug the ComboBox `Click` event handler? Are you sure it's not doing anything?

Comment: Thank you@ashes999. I don't have event subscribed to the Click.

Comment: I made a sample application based on your descriptions. The only difference is I didn't add highlighten feature. How do you know that it has refreshed? I found that when you set the SelectTab property on the TabControl, the TreeView will lost focus and get focus again. It would sometimes have effect like the TreeView 'refreshed'. I recommend you to remove the AfterSelect event handler and see if it happens again. You can select the TabPage which has ComboBox by default.

Comment: Hi@xtu, thanks for the reply. You just remind me something, it's after I add this highlighting SelectedNode feature, I start to see this refresh problem.